# IPFS Error: pin: block was not found locally (offline): ipld: could not find bafybeiciow

Tags: command-line

I have ipfs daemon running (confirmed via `sudo systemctl status ipfs`). But when I ran `ipfs pin add bafybeig6qkww7gaksmddvmn3n4nrbsnb2gqwjrhluacvc73yytiblf3wdy` I got the below...

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-57:~$ ipfs pin add bafybeig6qkww7gaksmddvmn3n4nrbsnb2gqwjrhluacvc73yytiblf3wdy
Error: pin: block was not found locally (offline): ipld: could not find bafybeig6qkww7gaksmddvmn3n4nrbsnb2gqwjrhluacvc73yytiblf3wdy
```

Googled but no joy.